# Google Cloud Build doesn't trigger on Github push with Dockerfile

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, deployment, cloud, google-cloud-build

I'm deploying an app using cloud build
I successfully completed the first and second steps (Build, Push)
But it gets stuck in the third step (Deploy) as you can see :

[image]

I have this error in the log

```
....
Step #2 - "Deploy": 17286105493c: Pull complete
Step #2 - "Deploy": 17447fff6ed6: Pull complete
Step #2 - "Deploy": Digest: sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Step #2 - "Deploy": Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim
Step #2 - "Deploy": gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim
Step #2 - "Deploy": Deploying...
Step #2 - "Deploy": Creating Revision............interrupted
Step #2 - "Deploy": Deployment failed
Step #2 - "Deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update) Revision 'xxxxxxxxxxx-00041-sux' is not ready and cannot serve traffic.
Finished Step #2 - "Deploy"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: I suspect there are additional log entries that you've not included that may explain the issue. Your question says "Cloud Build doesn't trigger" but it is evidently running. The issue appears to be that `gcloud run services deploy` is failing and this is probably because there's an issue with the code that you're trying to deploy to Cloud Run. Without  more details, it's not possible to provide guidance but I recommend you check your code including the Dockerfile to ensure that it meets Cloud Run's requirements (including listening on port 8080).

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you for your comment, I added more log, however I have the same image up and running on Cloud run. From my point of view the problem is related to 'cloud-sdk:slim' !

Comment: Thank you! It's possible the image being used is problematic but I think it's more likely that there's some error in your code changes (that triggered the build). Please include the Cloud Run logs. The easiest way to find the Cloud Run logs is to visit https://console.cloud.google.com/run ensure the project is correct, select the service (`xxxxxxxxxxx`) and then click `LOGS`.